# Use javascript variable in html to hide/show html tag

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, cookies

I am trying to show/hide html tag based on the cookie value.
I can do this by assigning ID to that anchor tag and set its display none in javascript but **I want to this in html only**.

**Example code:**

*Get the CompanyName from cookie.*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var companyName = getCookie("GlobalCompanyName"));
});
```

*Want to do something like this.*

```
<div class="coach_title_row">
  <% if (companyName == "XYZ" )
  { %>
     <a class="new" href="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/")%>Reports/Tool/Step1.aspx" title="Create New Report"><img src="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/")%>Static/V3/Images/ReportingTool/new_report.png"/></a>
<% } %>
</div>
```

I know how to do this using jQuery but I just don't want to use it. I am asking if it is possible to use a jQuery variable inside the html for comparison (in an if/else statement).

Comment: Question inside your question.  What kind of code goes inside `<% %>`?

Answer (score 0):

At first I wondered why not just use regular javascript/jquery? However upon looking at the code you gave us I think you may need a workaround. The solution seems fairly simple, so I think I am probably not understanding your question quite right, perhaps more detail about the stack you are using would help?

Here is the way to do this with simple simple jQuery. However this will most likely not work given your setup, explanation below.

```
var companyName;
var myHtml = "<a href="#">Whatever you need here</a>;

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   companyName = getCookie("GlobalCompanyName"));
   if(companyName == 'xyz'){
     jQuery('.coach_title_row).append(myHtml);
   }
});
```

Now, having said that, it seems like you are using ASP from the templating notation. Why not just get the cookie value within your controller and pass it into your view? It would be much cleaner than trying to use javascript in this situation.

Also, you may run into some issues with lazy loading if you are using javascript to insert html that contains templated attributes. The html will load, but none of the back end stuff will render because the javascript is inserting this content while running on the client side.

A work around would be to insert the link into your view, then use javascript to 'show' the div on page load if the cookie is correct.

html:

```
div class="coach_title_row">

     <a class="new" **style="display"none"**; href="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/")%>Reports/Tool/Step1.aspx" title="Create New Report">

  <img src="<%=   this.ResolveUrl("~/")%>Static/V3/Images/ReportingTool/new_report.png"/>

    </a>

</div>
```

Script:

```
var companyName;

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   companyName = getCookie("GlobalCompanyName"));
   // Instead just show the link already loaded, given cookie is correct
   if(companyName == 'xyz'){
     jQuery('.new').css('display','block');
   }
});
```

Comment: I know how to do this using jQuery but I just don't want to use this method. I am queries to know that anyhow we can use that jQuery variable inside the html for comparison (in if/else).